# Android : draw arc without resetting the previous drawn circle

Tags: android, animation, draw

I am trying to draw a circle which will represent time and after each complete circle, I want to change the color to indicate to the user that the next time unit has started and draw over the previous circle color rather than reset as shown in the example below.

I am trying to draw a circle using Draw Arc method in the following way

```
canvas.drawArc(mRect, 270, sweepAngle, false, fgPaint);
```

The sweep angle is controlled by an Object Animator :

```
outerCircleAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(timeView, TimeView.SET_SWEEPWANGLE, 0, 360);
```

With the following code, I am able to achieve the following 
[image]

The following is my View class :

```
public class TimeView extends View {

final protected Paint bgPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
final protected Paint fgPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
final protected Paint textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private RectF mRect = new RectF();
private float sweepAngle;
private float radiusInDPI = 100;
private float radiusInPixels;
private float strokeWidthInDPI = 4;
private float stokeWidthInPixels;
private float dpi;
private int heightByTwo;
private int widthByTwo;

public TimeView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public TimeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public TimeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

@Override
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    heightByTwo = h / 2;
    widthByTwo = w / 2;
    mRect = new RectF(w / 2 - radiusInPixels, h / 2 - radiusInPixels, w / 2 + radiusInPixels, h / 2 + radiusInPixels);
}

private void init() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    dpi = metrics.density;
    radiusInPixels = dpi * radiusInDPI;
    stokeWidthInPixels = dpi * strokeWidthInDPI;
    bgPaint.setStrokeWidth(stokeWidthInPixels);
    bgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    bgPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorAccent));

    fgPaint.setStrokeWidth(stokeWidthInPixels);
    fgPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    fgPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));

    textPaint.setTextSize(24 * 3);
    textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    textPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));


}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
   // canvas.drawCircle(widthByTwo, heightByTwo, radiusInPixels, bgPaint);
    canvas.drawArc(mRect, 270, sweepAngle, false, fgPaint);
}


public static final Property<TimeView, Float> SET_SWEEPWANGLE =
        new Property<TimeView, Float>(Float.class, "outerCircleRadiusProgress") {
            @Override
            public Float get(TimeView object) {
                return object.getSweepAngle();
            }

            @Override
            public void set(TimeView object, Float value) {
                object.setSweepAngle(value);
            }
        };

public float getSweepAngle() {
    return sweepAngle;
}

public void setSweepAngle(float sweepAngle) {
    Log.v("Testing", "Sweep angle is " + sweepAngle + " " + (sweepAngle + 270));
    this.sweepAngle = sweepAngle;
    postInvalidate();
}

public void setColor(boolean change) {
    if (change) {
        fgPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.mint_green));
    } else {
        fgPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onDraw is used to draw on the empty canvas. It is always starting from the beginning. You'll need to save the last fgPaint and:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (lastFgPaint != null) {
        canvas.drawArc(mRect, sweepAngle, 360, false, lastFgPaint);
    }
    canvas.drawArc(mRect, 270, sweepAngle, false, fgPaint);
}
```

Comment: That's a good answer. Thank you. But we are essentially drawing again with the same color.  I was wondering was wondering was, is there a way to just draw over the previous color? As in save the previous canvas and draw over that canvas?  Sorry if that's a stupid question

Comment: no it's not stupid, but my 1st sentence explains why that doesn't work like that :) [not that I understand what do you achieve by drawing again and again with the same color]